# make Selenium not think something is loading in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have some tests that work fine on chrome and firefox but with IE they seem to get to some page (not always the same one) and then stay there for a long time doing nothing. I am using IE 11(latest version ) on windows 7 and selenium 3.0.1 and ie driver 2.53.1 . I tried going to some old selenium version with old ie driver versions but I can't find a stable combination.

So my question is If i want to run the tests on IE 11 what version of selenium and ie driver should I use??

**UPDATE:**

I now know the cause of the problem. There is an input option, when it is selected a form shows , Selenium thinks some script is still loading although it has finished and stays waiting forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try once using `Actions` as
`Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.sendKeys(element, "Testingusername");`

Comment: and then act.perform();

Answer (score 1):

@mosaad

I am running my tests on IE for which I am using both Selenium and IE Driver of version 2.53.1. I also had the same issue when I moved to Selenium 3.0.1, but I downgraded. So you can check with the Selenium 2.53.1. It should fine.

Comment: I tried using 2.53.1 for both, it is less buggy but still hangs at one page

Comment: its not the problem with the code it works with other browsers. Anyways the part where it stops is element.click(); then  element.sendKeys(keys);

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "it stops"?
Clarify me on:
1. What is the error you are getting?
2. Is the element visible and enabled?
3. Is this element in a frame?
Try hardcoding wait (Sleep) before and after the "Click" action and check if it works.

Comment: The problem is it does nothing, it just stays on the page. It stops after the click so clicking is not the problem. It should type something in an input text field and that is what is not working. I added 2 seconds sleeps before and after. It does not help

Comment: The element is enabled. I tried manually to type and it works

Comment: Sorry to point it out late, but Is "Keys" in `element.sendKeys(keys)` a variable? If not then edit it like `element.sendKeys("keys")`

If your textbox has placeholder, then try clearing it first with `element.clear();`

Even if these tries doesn`t works, then try once using `Actions` as `Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.sendKeys(element, "Testingusername");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129805/discussion-between-ashish-and-mosaad).

Comment: using actions worked. write it in answer so i accept it. Thx alot :)

Comment: Yeeeh..Finally :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [Selenium with IE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration)